# How do I get the value from the Label that is in the StackPanel in the Button?

Tags: c, wpf

How do I get the value from the Label that is in the StackPanel in the Button?

```
<Button Width="auto" Height="40" Click="GoAds" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="/Resours/Icons/Basket.png"
         Width="24" Height="24"/>
        <Label Content="Proc"
         FontSize="20" Foreground="Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

How to get the value of the Content property of the clicked button in the conditional variable x?

I see it somehow, but something is missing

```
String X = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
```

Comment: Hey Hahlito, @mm8 answer will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
String X = (((sender as Button)?.Content as StackPanel).Children[1] as Label)?
    .Content?.ToString();
```

You need to cast the `Content` as a `StackPanel` and then access the `Label` in the `StackPanel`'s `Children` collection.